# Download PDF from Hugo Site

Tags: pdf, hugo

I'm having a helluva time trying to figure how to link and download a pdf on my Hugo site.

I use `[Download Resume](/static/Resume.pdf)` and it creates the link but I get a 404 error even though it's definitely the correct path.

I bet I'm missing something extremely basic but neither by Hugo guidebook nor their documentation makes it clear on how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Well, all I had to do was remove the /static/ direction and it worked. Hope this might help someone in the future!